# Categories, Single and Channels ....SEO

Tags: templating, categories, seo

Background... I took a look at [this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14903/product-categories-structures-and-channels) answered by @Damon

My objective is similar.  I have a channel for news.  Each entry in news is assigned various categories (e.g. product category).

I do not have a "single" in Craft for each product category.  However, I do have a `_productCategory.html` template.  And each product category has its own page. ...that is, `productCategory/{slug}` with `{slug}` being an individual product category.   And I have a link to each product category in my nav.   I know, pretty basic.

I know there are multiple ways to skin the cat, but am I missing out on anything by not using a single for each product category page?  Is there any impact on SEO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to throw out some pure speculation here that Google and other bots are going to want something to be at "/productCategory/". Hell, I'll even delete a slug when navigating a website. Whether it be via just a template that links subcategories, a single, part of structure, or categories, take the opportunity to create more landing pages.(just don't overdo it).

My only suggestion would be to make the category trigger word something other than "productCategory" or "category" or "cat" etc. Below I am using "cars" as the category trigger.

```
/cars/imported/fiat
```

And there is content on "/cars/", "/imported/", and "/fiat".

Comment: I am using real category names, like plane.  I just did not want to list them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some things to consider with SEO and URLs:

- Readability of the url
- Including keywords in the url
- Shorter > longer
- Fewer /folders/ in the url
- Generally don't want any caps in the URL
- Separate words with hyphens or underscores

So, "/particular-product-title" would be preferable to "/productCategory/particular-product"

Hope that's helpful!